# Is it a good idea majoring in data science for undergraduate?

Tags: data

Is it a good idea majoring in data science for undergraduate?

Auckland University offers an undergraduate major in data science, which has courses in computer science and statistics.

I read somewhere that it's a bad idea to to undergraduate in data science.

Comment: TL;DR it's a **good** idea. People working on data science these days may have different backgrounds (engineering, computer science, mathematics, statistics, economics, etc.). This is because there was no "data science" curriculum 10 years ago. Things won't stay like that forever, though. There is a clear demand for data scientists and universities around the world are striving to meet this demand. In a few years, when this demand is finally met, I suspect companies will stop hiring data scientists with a mixed background. Pretty much the same thing happened with programmers in the 70s/80s.